# problem with QueueRecieving value in FreeRTOS

Tags: esp32, freertos

I'm implement task handler for GUI task by using LVGL and FreeRTOS in ESP32

Whenever I get queue message, I read message as 0 in handler.

When I send message, It is fine.

LOG:

```
I (105690) wifi_app: WIFI_APP_MSG_STA_DISCONNECTED: USER REQUESTED DISCONNECTION
I (105700) LVGL: SEND MESSAGE
I (105700) LVGL: SENDING msgID 4 // when send
I (105710) LVGL: RECEVING msgID: 0 // read message in handler
I (105710) LVGL: Get NTU from sensor
I (105720) http_server: HTTP_MSG_WIFI_USER_DISCONNECT
```

Handler: Parsing message Id by using switch statement

```
static void cmd_parsing(void *arg)
{
    lvgl_queue_message_t lvglMsg;

    for (;;)
    {

        if (xQueueReceive(lvgl_queue_handle, &lvglMsg, portMAX_DELAY))
        {

            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Recieving msgID: %d", lvglMsg.msgID);
            switch (lvglMsg.msgID)
            {
                case LVGL_MSG_SEND_NTU:
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Get NTU from sensor");
                        //                    lv_label_set_text(label_ntu, evt.string1);
                        lv_label_set_text_fmt(label_ntu, "%0.3f NTU", lvglMsg.valueFloat);
                        break;
                case LVGL_MSG_WIFI_CONNECT_INIT:
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Create spinner for connecting Wi-Fi");

                        create_spinner();

                        xSemaphoreGive(xGuiSemaphore);
                    break;
                case LVGL_MSG_WIFI_USER_DISCONNECT:

                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "WIFI_USER_DISCONNECT");

                        lv_obj_clean(settings_tab);
                        create_list_settings();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Send: Sending message Id in WIFI task

```
BaseType_t lvgl_send_message(lvgl_message_e msgID)
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SEND MESSAGE");
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Sending msgID %d", msgID);
    lvgl_queue_message_t lvglMsg;
    lvglMsg.msgID = msgID;
    return xQueueSend(lvgl_queue_handle, &lvglMsg, portMAX_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]. At least show lvgl_queue_message_t and the code that does xQueueCreate.

Comment: @ rustyx Thanks for comment. I think I solved problem. I created queue wrongly and I used timer as lvgl task. I noticed that timer of LVGL v8 is working as task.